# C# PInvoke CryptImportKey Fails with "Invalid type specified"

Tags: c#, certificate, smartcard, advapi32, gemalto

I'm trying to use the CryptImportKey function to import a PFX into a Gemalto .NET IDPrime smart cart, but I'm getting a "Invalid Type Specified" (2148073482) error.  I suspect that the RSACryptoServiceProvider.ExportCspBlob(true) call is returning the keys in the wrong format.  I'm using sample code from http://www.idrix.fr/Root/Samples/PfxImporter.cs.  NOTE: I've already set the AllowPrivateExchangeKeyImport & AllowPrivateSignatureKeyImport to 0x1 for the Microsoft Base Smart Card Crypto Provider, but still no change.  I'm running Windows Server 2012, but don't think that is the issue.

Can someone please tell me what is wrong with this code sample?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is certainly caused by the fact that your application is 32-bit running on a 64-bit Windows and you didn't change the Microsoft Base CSP 32-bit registry key located under **Wow6432Node**.

To solve your issue, change AllowPrivateExchangeKeyImport & AllowPrivateSignatureKeyImport also under "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Cryptography\Defaults\Provider\Microsoft Base Smart Card Crypto Provider".

I have update the comment in [PfxImporter.cs](https://www.idrix.fr/Root/Samples/PfxImporter.cs) header to include this remark.